# Things to keep in mind for the public beta

Tags: discussion

During the private beta, we have discussed a number of topics involving the running of this site. The relevant discussions are as follows:

1. [Current ideas about tagging](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/104/52),
2. [Links as answers](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/78/52),
3. [Whether questions about other Wolfram Research products are on topic](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/68/52),
4. [Migration from SO](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/53/52) and [Re-asking questions from SO here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/124/52),
5. [TagWiki contents](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/95/52),
6. [LaTeX vs. Code blocks](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/52),
7. [Code blocks vs. pictures of code](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97/52),
8. [Including code samples](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/52)
9. [Entering backticks for package names](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/52), and
10. [Voting](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22/52).

If you have any questions, concerns, or disagreements with the above, please post on the relevant discussion or discuss it on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica).

Additionally, for the so inclined, there is an [image uploader palette](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/52) for uploading images directly from Mathematica to [Mathematica.se](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Also, LaTeX is enabled via [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) on this site. It is possible to extend this to the chat room, also, by following the directions [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html).

As a final note, voting on meta is a little different than on the normal site. It does not confer reputation, and an upvote (downvote) indicates that you agree/like (disagree/dislike) the post.